# Send a Meeting Request with System.Net.Mail

Tags: asp.net, outlook, timezone

I am using [this example code](http://www.ahmedblog.com/Blogs/ShowBlog.aspx?Id=2dc7e9e7-92b4-48cc-a7d1-d6535e5554ab) to send a meeting request. I am having a problem: every time I use the code, the meeting time is always the wrong time.

For example: `DTSTART:20120710T143000Z` gives an appointment in Outlook `Tuesday, July 10, 2012 4:30 PM-5:30 PM` when it should give `Tuesday, July 10, 2012 2:30 PM-3:30 PM`. Why is that happening?

Our local time is UTC/GMT +3 (Jordan Standard Time) in the summer and UTC/GMT +2 in the winter. Every time I make an appointment through outlook it is always the right time.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Does he? `14h 30m 00s`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The start time you place in your appointment should be a UTC time. I suspect you are a inserting local (Jordan) time. This explains the two hour difference, because afaik UTC does not take daylight saving time into account.

SO resources:

1. [Convert somebody's local time to the UTC time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412611/convert-somebodys-local-time-to-the-utc-time)
2. [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices)
3. [Convert UTC/GMT time to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/c-sharp-convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time)

Comment: thanks ill try the resources and see if any works for me and get back to you.

Comment: I used ToUniversalTime() function to convert the time to UTC and that did the trick.
thanks.

Comment: That's great. Consider accepting this answer so everybody knows your question was solved.